# top left logo scroll to stop of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add some text on the top left corner of my nav bar. Upon click, I want the page to automatically scroll back up to the top of the page

HTML:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <a id="logo" href=".navbar">LOGO HERE</a>
    <ul id="nav_pills" class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation">
        <a id="test" href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#team">Team</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

My JS so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // easing scroll bluhd
    var hrefObjects = $("li a");
    hrefObjects.push($(".welcome-btn"));
    hrefObjects.push($("#logo"));
    hrefObjects.each(function() {
        $(this).on("click", function(e) {
            var mode = "easeInOutQuart";
            e.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
            }, 750, mode);
        });
    })
});
```

I am currently getting this error and I am not sure how to fix this.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

`.push()` is not a valid jQuery function. `hrefObjects` is a jQuery object, not an array.

Simplify it to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li a, .welcome-btn, #logo").on("click", null, function(e) {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 750, "easeInOutQuart");
        return false; // prevents default
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy to do, using the jQuery `animate()` method.  Here's an example of how you could do it - very simple.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 //Click event to scroll to top
 $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
  return false;
 });
 
});
```

```css
.scrollToTop{
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="scrollToTop">Company Name</a>

Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>Bla<br>
```

Hope this helps, and comment below if I can help you further.